# Check checkboxes based on database values

Tags: php, html

I have values in a database, like dates and checkbox values. I want to check boxes which have dates in the database; other checkboxes should be empty. How to have the correct checkboxes (out of 30) checked?.

```
<?php 
for($i = 1; $i <= $no_of_days; $i++) {
  if($i == 15 || $i == 18) {
    ?>
    <div style="width:300px;float:left;">
      <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="isactive" checked="checked" />
      <?php echo $start = date(''.$i.'-m-Y'); ?>
      </br></br></br>       
    </div>
    <?php
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: `if (($i = 15) || ($i == 18)) { add 'checked' attribute to checkbox' }`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you need :

```
<?php 
    for($i=1;$i<=20;$i++) {
        if($i ==15 || $i== 18) {
            $is_checked = 'checked';
        } ?>

        <div style = "width : 300px; float : left;" >
            <input type = "checkbox" value = "1" name = "isactive"
                <?php echo $is_checked; ?>
                <?php
                   if( @$isActive[$i] == 1 ) { ?> 
                       checked = "checked" <?php
                   } ?> 
            />

            <?php echo $start = date(''.$i.'-m-Y'); ?>

            </br></br></br>     
        </div> <?php
    } ?>
```

Give it a try

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
  for( $i = 1; $i <= $no_of_days; $i++) {
?>
    <div style="width: 300px; float: left;">
        <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="isactive"
            <?php if( $i == 15 || $i == 18 ) { echo "checked=\"checked\""; } ?> />
        <?php echo $start = date( $i.'-m-Y' ); ?>
        <br /><br /><br />
    </div>
<?php
  }
?>
```

Proper indentation helps a lot.

Comment: it works in this case but i have different case, my data is in foreach and i m not able to do it

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php for($i = 0; $i <= $no_of_days; $i++): ?>
  <div class="wrap">
    <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="isactive" <?=($i == 15 || $i == 18)?'checked="checked"':''?>>
    <?php echo $start = date(''.$i.'-m-Y'); ?>
  </div>
<? endfor; ?>


.wrap {
    float:left;
    width:300px;
```

}